# Branching dialogue in python

Tags: python

I am teaching myself python in my spare time. I've only been at it for a couple days so for practice I've been messing around with various raw_input lines. Currently I am trying to make a short text-venture for a friend to try out. I have hit a block, part of it asks the user if they want to enter a village. If they choose to enter, everything works just fine, but if they choose not to, I need it to jump down past all of the dialogue and inputs that happen while inside the village. How do I make it jump down to an input further down the page?

it's very basic but here:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name adventurer? ")
where = raw_input("You are in a magical forest, you can go North or East, which 
way do you go?")
if where.lower() == "north":
    troll = raw_input("You encounter a troll, what do you do? Attack or flee? ")
else:
    print("You encounter a dragon, you are dead, GAME OVER")
if troll.lower() == "attack":
    print ("You have no weapon, that was a bad choice, you are dead, GAME OVER")
else:
    flee = raw_input("You flee further North, you encounter a village, do you 
enter or continue? ")
if flee.lower() == "enter":
    army = raw_input("As you enter the village, a knight hands you a sword, 
assuming you are there to join the army. Join him or leave the village? ")
else:
    print ("You ignore the village and continue down the road.") #jump from here
if army.lower() == "join":
    print ("You head off to war and are killed almost instantly because you are an 
untrained fool")
else:
    print ("You are kicked out of the village")
dark = raw_input("It is getting dark, do you continue or seek shelter") #to here
if dark.lower() == "continue":
    print ("You are attacked by vampires and killed, GAME OVER")
else:
    caves = raw_input("You find two caves, do you pick cave one which is pitch 
black, or two which has light coming from it? ")
if caves.lower() == "one":
    print ("You enter the cave, light a small fire, and sleep for the night.")
else:
    print ("You enter the cave, there are bandits inside, you are murdered, GAME OVER")
```

I want to jump down to **dark** after the first bold line. If anything else is spotted that could be fixed or made better, please do speak up. All criticism is welcome.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33811111/edit) your question and [format your code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/1555990) properly.

Comment: FWIW, part of the reason for that formatting is so we can cut and paste your complete code into an editor and run it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

change this block:

```
if flee.lower() == "enter":
    army = raw_input("As you enter the village, a knight hands you a sword, 
assuming you are there to join the army. Join him or leave the village? ")
else:
    print ("You ignore the village and continue down the road.") #jump from here
if army.lower() == "join":
    print ("You head off to war and are killed almost instantly because you are an 
untrained fool")
else:
    print ("You are kicked out of the village")
dark = raw_input("It is getting dark, do you continue or seek shelter")
```

into this block:

```
if flee.lower() == "enter":
    army = raw_input("As you enter the village, a knight hands you a sword, 
assuming you are there to join the army. Join him or leave the village? ")
    if army.lower() == "join":
        print ("You head off to war and are killed almost instantly because you are an 
untrained fool")
    else:
        print ("You are kicked out of the village")
else:
    print ("You ignore the village and continue down the road.")
dark = raw_input("It is getting dark, do you continue or seek shelter")
```

This moves the `army` input to inside of the `enter` block so that it will only execute if it goes inside that statement.

A few notes:
you probably want to put this all inside a `main()` function and call `return` whenever you die so that it wont continue. Another choice, if you dont want to use a function, is to put everything inside a `try` block and call `raise` if you die, then handle death with your `except` block. You say you are a beginner so you might not have learned this stuff yet but it's definitely something to look into